# JavaScript's setTimeout doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have a simple JS object which emulates traffic lights:

```
function TrafficLight(redTime, yellowTime, greenTime) {
    var self = this;

    this.__timer = null;
    this.__state = null;
    this.__redTime = redTime;
    this.__yellowTime = yellowTime;
    this.__greenTime = greenTime;

    var setnewtimer = function (delay, func) {
        console.log('SET!');
        if (self.__timer) {
            clearTimeout(this.__timer);
        }
        self.__timer = setTimeout(delay, func);
    };

    TrafficLight.prototype.toRed = function () {
        this.__state = 'red';
        setnewtimer(this.__redTime, function () {
            console.log('RED!');
            self.toGreen();
        });
    };

    TrafficLight.prototype.toGreen = function () {
        this.__state = 'green';
        setnewtimer(this.__greenTime, function () {
            console.log('GREEN');
            self.toYellow();
        });
    };

    TrafficLight.prototype.toYellow = function () {
        this.__state = 'yellow';
        setnewtimer(this.__yellowTime, function () {
            console.log('YELLOW');
            self.toRed();
        });
    };

    TrafficLight.prototype.state = function () {
        return this.__state;
    };

    this.toGreen();
}
```

But when I make a `TrafficLight` object (like `var a = new TrafficLight(1000, 1000, 1000);`), every `a.state()` call returns `green` (so traffic light doesn't change its state by timer. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: *"JavaScript's setTimeout doesn't work"* It does, you know. But it's not JavaScript's, it's the browser's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't call [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) correctly.

Change

```
setTimeout(delay, func);
```

to

```
setTimeout(func, delay);
```

Comment: @OliverWatkins That's true, but in cases like this the first thing I would check was the documentation of the function that isn't working.